# Prove $[a,b] \sim (c,d]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Q: Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are real numbers, prove $[a,b] \sim (c,d]$.

My thought: If the question was "prove $[a,b] \sim [c,d]$" then take the first interval on the x-axis and the second one on y-axis. Then we can define a function like $y=c+ \frac{d-c}{b-a}(x-a)$ that maps all the points in $[a, b]$ to $[c,d]$.
However the interval in the question is different. I don't know how to apply the idea to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f:[a,b]\to(c,d]$ by

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}d&\text{ if }x=a\\ c+\frac{d-c}{n+1}&\text{ if }\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:x = a+\frac{b-a}{n}\\ \frac{d-c}{b-a}(x-a)+c &\text{ if else}\end{cases}$$

You can show $f$ to be injective after ruling out the case where $$f(x_1)=c+\frac{d-c}{n+1}=\frac{d-c}{b-a}(x_2-a)+c=f(x_2)$$ for some $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ along with a couple other cases.

To show surjectivity, show that $$(c,d]\supset\left\{y\in(c,d):\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:y=c+\frac{d-c}{n+1}\right\}=S$$ with strict inclusion.

Then, if $y\in(c,d]$, either $y$ is in the $S$ or it is not.

If $y=d$, then $f(a)=d$.

If $y\in(c,d)$, and not in $S$, then choose $$x=a+\frac{b-a}{d-c}(y-c)$$ so that $f(x)=y$

Otherwise, $y\in S$, so
$$y=c+\frac{d-c}{n+1}$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so choose $$x=a+\frac{b-a}{n}$$ to get $f(x)=y$.